# How to make generic Appium find_element_by_xpath method?

Tags: android, python, selenium, appium

I am writing test cases for my application but i have a problem. When i use Genymotion for emulator. I got this path on Appium inspector and create my script for this path:

```
"//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.view.ViewPager[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.Button[1]"
```

But if i use device "HTC One E8". I got this path on Appium inspector:

```
"//android.support.v4.view.ViewPager[1]/android.widget.Button[1]"
```

my script will fail? if i use different devices and emulators. 
How can it be generic?.

PS: I used `self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().resourceId("welcome_button_meet_hopi")').click()` before but it works on Appium on Ubuntu and it didnt work on Appium on OSX

Comment: If you noticed, `//android.support.v4.view.ViewPager[1]/android.widget.Button[1]` is a substring of the larger xpath.  Think of // as the starting point of the search. If //android.support.v4.view.ViewPager[1] is a unique element, you can use it as the starting point. In addition, using more identifying attributes like name and id should be used if you want your xpath to be more consistent. Check out this xpath cheat sheet for more info: http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.png

Comment: @econoMichael  can you please share that cheet sheet link, any how i am getting blur image.

Comment: @Mert can you please share the screenshot of your UIAutomator screen

Comment: @sameerjoshi Sorry, I linked the thumbnail. Here you go: http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf

Comment: @econoMichael thank you